# What is Werster referring to when he says "And I got trips on my money" at the end of a Pokemon Blue run?

Tags: terminology, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, speedrun

Can be seen in this video at 05:49:

What was Werster talking about? Was there some sort of bet involved with someone else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Trips" is short for "triple digits". He's just referring to the fact that the last three digits of his in-game money were the same number:

[image: Money at $45222]

Comment: Thanks! Why does Werster care about that?

Comment: @Fiksdal I'd say he just thought it was neat, rather than caring about it in any way. The same way someone might point out a pink car or an oddly-shaped cloud.